# Excel file downloaded through Wordpress rest api is corrupted

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on an application in wordpress that need the ability to download a report. When the user selects the export option I will make a call to the Wordpress rest api, which makes a call to the client's api that generates and return the necessary report. When exporting a csv everything works fine, but when trying to export an xlsx the file is "corrupted". Calling the client's api endpoint directly through postman works and returns a functional excel file. But when making the exact same call through wordpress the literal string value of the file is returned, wrapped in quotes and with escape characters for characters with no visual representation (for example the byte of value 0x14 is returned as \n0020). I have all of the combinations of setting the content-type header to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`, `application/octet-stream`, and the content encoding to binary.

The wordpress code doing the api call and returning the result is

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);

$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);
$array_data;

if ($err)
{
    $resData['message'] = "cURL Error #:" . $err;
}
else if( $code === 401 )
{
    $resData['message'] = "Client session has expired. Please re login.";
}
else
{
    $resData = $data;
}

$debug["endpoint"] = $endpoint;
$debug["token"] = $token;

return $resData;
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference the issue is the line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` delete that and it is not returned as literal string. The file is still "corrupted" but that appears to be an issue with office, as opening it in notepad++ and saving it without making any changes makes it readable. Additionally when comparing the file in a hex editor there is no difference between the original readable file, the "corrupted" file, and the "fixed" file.